# What is difference between ng-init and ng-bind?

Tags: html, angularjs

Below is the code using ng-init:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="" ng-init="names=['Jani','Hege','Kai']">
  <p>Looping with ng-repeat:</p>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="x in names">
      {{ x }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Below is the code using ng-bind:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="" ng-bind="names=['Jani','Hege','Kai']">
  <p>Looping with ng-repeat:</p>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="x in names">
      {{ x }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Both give the same output, with different formats.

What exactly is happening here ?

Please help!

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The purpose of [ng-init](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) is initialize a property in template.

The purpose of [ng-bind](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBind) is replace the text content of the specified HTML element with the value of a given expression.

But you should initialize the variable in controller and use `{{variable}}` and don´t use ng-init or ng-bind for this.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

`ng-bind` and `ng-init` have very different use cases.

`ng-bind` is for assigning inner text to element, like:

```
<div ng-bind="'hi'"><div>
```

results in:

```
<div>hi</div>
```

`ng-init` directive is executed once and is mainly useful for declaring variables. So in your case you shall use `ng-init`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.